# Pandas keep only index with values in both columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with an index called `SubjectID` two columns with integer values. I want to keep only Subjects that have values in the `Value 1` column and the `Value 2` column, and get rid of Subjects that have only one value.

Here is an example of my data frame:

```
SubjectID    Value1    Value2
B1            1.57      1.75
B2            N/A       1.56
```

So I would only want to keep the first row. Here is the code I have written so far:

```
df_to_add = []
for sub in df.index:
    values = df.loc[df.index]['Value1']['Value2']
    if type(values) is pd.Series: # check that subject had multiple values, don't want otherwise
        array = values.values
        if "'Value1'" in scans_array and "'Value2'" in array:
            df_to_add.append(df.loc[df.index])
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `N/A` is an actual `NaN`, you can simply `.dropna()` your DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'SubjectID': ['B1', 'B2'],
                   'Value1': [1.57, float('nan')],
                   'Value2': [1.75, 1.56]})
df = df.set_index('SubjectID')

print(df)
#            Value1  Value2
# SubjectID                
# B1           1.57    1.75
# B2            NaN    1.56

print(df.dropna())
#            Value1  Value2
# SubjectID                
# B1           1.57    1.75
```